# how to install citrix client on windows 7.5?

Tags: apps

Just wondering if anyone had experience on installing the citrix client on the windows 7.5? If yes, can some one please share their experience on how to do it step by step?

I already searched for it but to no avail.

P.S: I tried to access a citrix URL with my Mobile IE, which did let me login, but can't open any application since it can't recognize the ICA file!

Comment: Well, is there a Citrix app? Have you tried installing that?

Answer (score 1):

The is currently no Citrix app for Windows Phone. You may wish to check Citrix downloads page to see if it becomes available   http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_2309126.asp

Comment: there are two file formats available for download .exe and .cab but none of them are supported in Mango

Comment: @Nandakumar Those downloads are for Windows *Mobile* not Windows *Phone*